# Capturing JavaScript Events in C# from YouTube API Using Awesomium

Tags: c#, javascript, wpf, youtube-api, awesomium

Am I able to capture a JavaScript event, in C#, when generated as a result of the YouTube API while running in Awesomium?

I have the following HTML which I load into my Awesomium browser:

```
<body>
    <div id="player"></div>

    <script src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>
    <script>
        var player;

        function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
            player = new YT.Player('player', {
                height: '390',
                width: '640',
                videoId: '0Bmhjf0rKe8',
                events: {
                    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
            });
        }

        function onPlayerReady(event) {
            event.target.playVideo();
        }

        function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
            if (event.data == 0) {
                alert('done');
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

How can I capture the `onPlayerStateChange` (or another event generated by it) back in the C#, so that my application can react when the video ends?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided you're using Awesomium.NET 1.7 RC, here are the steps to do it:

- Create a global JavaScript object. See: [`CreateGlobalJavascriptObject`](http://docs.awesomium.net/?tc=M_Awesomium_Core_IWebView_CreateGlobalJavascriptObject)
- Add a custom method to the global JS object, and bind to it. See: [`JSObject.Bind`](http://docs.awesomium.net/?tc=M_Awesomium_Core_JSObject_Bind)
- Call the custom method from inside your `onPlayerStateChange` handler:

  ```
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
      if (event.data == 0) {
          myGlobalObject.onPlayerStateChange();
      }
  }
  ```

(The example assumes you created a global JS object named *myGlobalObject* and you added a *onPlayerStateChange* custom method to it.)

This will fire the `JavascriptMethodEventHandler` you defined at `JSObject.Bind`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know awesomium (never used it), so I can't tell if there is a "native" way to do that, but there is always the option to send a message to your program using ajax

You could set up a local `HttpServer` as explained [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25050/Embedded-NET-HTTP-Server) and then get the notifications you need.

You could also go with a simple `TcpListener` I think, which would be a lot simpler but will require some work to handle the http headers (but I think I saw a class that does it written in C# somewhere on the web, and it isn't very complex since you'll only have to manage the GET requests). If you think this can be a way to go I can write something more explicit in an edit of this post.

Anyway, hope this was helpful

Answer (score 0):

In short you want c# to listen to javascript event! Nice.

This is very easy using Awesomium.NET.

After droping the awesomium control into your form it will by default create an object

webControl1

in the form_load method create a document.ready like event handler, the added event will be invoked when the document is ready

```
webControl1.DocumentReady += webControl1_DocumentReady;
```

lets create a javascript method from c# (say `myGlobalObject.myMethod(){ }` ). the script will be injected into the page by awesomium. we will then listen for the event where the function is called from javascript.

you can even call this method from your `onPlayerStateChange`

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
   myGlobalObject.myMethod();
}
```

so that when your javascript event fires, it calls the javascript method `(myGlobalObject.myMethod();)` created in c#

so we need to create the global object and then the associated method like this

```
using (JSObject myGlobalObject = webControl1.CreateGlobalJavascriptObject("myGlobalObject"))
        {
            // The handler is of type JavascriptMethodEventHandler. Here we define it
            // using a lambda expression.
            myGlobalObject.Bind("myMethod", true, (s, ee) =>
            {
                // Provide a response.
                ee.Result = "My response";
            });
        }
```

this will carry out the necessary javascript object and method injection into your page.
so

in the webControl1_DocumentReady method (we attached earlier)
then you can  will have

```
 void webControl1_DocumentReady(object sender, UrlEventArgs e)
        {


            dynamic myGlobalObject_ = (JSObject)webControl1.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("myGlobalObject");
            using (myGlobalObject_)
            {
                myGlobalObject_.myMethod = (JavascriptMethodEventHandler)OnCustomJavascriptMethod;

            }
        }
```

you will have to create the OnCustomJavascriptMethod method like this (for example)

```
private void OnCustomJavascriptMethod(object sender, JavascriptMethodEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("hi");
        }
```

this method (OnCustomJavascriptMethod ) will be invoked in your c# when your javascript event onPlayerStateChange is invoked (because it will call  myGlobalObject.myMethod();)

thats all! wait for your onPlayerStateChange to fire and your method  OnCustomJavascriptMethod(object sender, JavascriptMethodEventArgs e) in c# will be called, hence making javascript "control C# methods"

you can find more information about awesomium  at https://awesomium.com/ you can download the sdk for windows at http://awesomium.com/downloads/awesomium_1_7_0_sdk_win.exe and get started.